# How to implememnt push notification in react pwa for apple

Tags: reactjs

I want to implenement pwa push notification for apple ios device. I have already implemented for android devices and it is working just fine.

Comment: iOS will not support this feature until sometime in 2023 according to Apple updates for iOS 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently apple's IOS does not support push notifications for pwa. Although it is expected to, sometime soon. Generally IOS does not support all the features  that android supports.

Comment: FWI the feature is still not available. I ve been trying to verify this for the past hour!